# How to assign a new column based on conditions of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to add a column, "flag_column" based on the value present in A, B, C, D.

i.e if there is a value in A / B / C / D I would like to create a new column, 'flag' indicating the column name that contains a value.

```
  A B C D counts flag
0 1 0 0 0  1     A
1 0 1 0 0  1     B
2 1 0 0 0  1     A
3 0 0 1 0  1     C
4 0 1 0 0  1     B
```

Note: There will only be one column (A through D) that contains a value, so counts will always be 1.

I've tried:

```
if [df['A'] == 1] == True:
    df['flag'] = 'A'
elif [df['B'] == 1] == True:
    df['flag'] = 'B'
elif [df['C'] == 1] == True:
    df['flag'] = 'C'  
else:
    df['flag'] = 'D'
```

I have also tried:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['A'] == 1, 'A', False)
df['flag'] = np.where(df['B'] == 1, 'B', False)
df['flag'] = np.where(df['C'] == 1, 'C', False)
df['flag'] = np.where(df['D'] == 1, 'D', False)
```

I've also tried doing this iteratively looping through each "category" and assigning a flag value, however it overwrites in these cases as well.

If there is a way in which I could iteratively do this, that would be ideal. However, any help on this (simple) question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `np.select` for multiple conditions:

```
df['flag'] = np.select([df['A'] == 1, df['B'] == 1, df['C'] == 1, df['D'] == 1],
                       ['A','B','C','D'],
                       False)
df

Out[1]:
    A   B   C   D   counts  flag
0   1   0   0   0   1       A
1   0   1   0   0   1       B
2   1   0   0   0   1       A
3   0   0   1   0   1       C
4   0   1   0   0   1       B
```

but for `np.where`, this is where you went wrong. You should have only written `False` the first time and then put the value of the column as the alternative for all of the remaining `np.where` statements:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['A'] == 1, 'A', False)
df['flag'] = np.where(df['B'] == 1, 'B', df['flag'])
df['flag'] = np.where(df['C'] == 1, 'C', df['flag'])
df['flag'] = np.where(df['D'] == 1, 'D', df['flag'])

Out[2]:
    A   B   C   D   counts  flag
0   1   0   0   0   1       A
1   0   1   0   0   1       B
2   1   0   0   0   1       A
3   0   0   1   0   1       C
4   0   1   0   0   1       B
```

As you can see though `np.select` is much more concise.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I knew I was going wrong somewhere with the np.where()

Answer (score 5):

We can use `idxmax` over `axis=1` here:

```
df['flag'] = df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].idxmax(axis=1)
```

```
   A  B  C  D flag
0  1  0  0  0    A
1  0  1  0  0    B
2  1  0  0  0    A
3  0  0  1  0    C
4  0  1  0  0    B
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with `dot`

```
df['flag'] = df.loc[:,'A':'D'].dot(df.columns[:4])
Out[108]: 
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    C
4    B
dtype: object
```

Comment: Notice the reason why I use dot not idxmax  : if same row have more than two 1 then idxmax will only return the first one , also , if all 0 idxmax will return the first value

Comment: `(axis=1)` is also very slow for large dataframes, but it's great for smaller dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['A'] == 1, 'A', 
    np.where(df['B'] == 1, 'B',
    np.where(df['C'] == 1, 'C',
    np.where(df['D'] == 1, 'D', '?'))))
```

Comment: Interesting, kind of reminds me of a nested IF excel statement. For future, I would check out `np.select` though. It is a lot cleaner and intuitive once you try it a couple times.

Comment: It's the first time I watch `np.where` used that way. That Working in effect, but I think we lose legibility using this method.

Comment: This is pretty common usage from what I've seen colleagues do in R with nested `ifelse` statements. Not sure of their efficiency though (the readability isn't that great imo)- interesting approach nonetheless!

Comment: @DavidErickson Yes, I think `np.select` is better, too.